# How to make a line fill effect with Paper.js?

Tags: javascript, paperjs

How to produce this kind of effect with `Paper.js` ?

[image]

(originally posted [here](https://gitter.im/paperjs/paper.js?at=5e1ca520a859c14fa1dc6961))

Answer (score 1):

You can divide your shape vertically into a given number of sections and then iterate over them and look for intersections between an horizontal line in the middle of the section and the shape.
You will then just have to draw a line between every couple of intersections.
This can be done quite simply with `Paper.js` as in this [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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).

```js
// Controls how many lines are used to draw the shape.
const LINES_COUNT = 30;

// Draw the shape to fill with lines.
const shape = new Path.Star({
    center: view.center,
    points: 7,
    radius1: 75,
    radius2: 150,
    // We make it selected to better understand what is happening.
    selected: true
});


// Divide the shape vertically into sections.
for (let i = 0; i < LINES_COUNT; i++) {
    // Calculate the y middle of the section.
    const y = shape.bounds.top + (i + 0.5) * (shape.bounds.height / LINES_COUNT);

    // Create a horizontal line crossing the shape.
    const line = new Path.Line({
        from: [0, y],
        to: [view.bounds.right, y]
    });

    // Get intersections between the shape and the line.
    const intersections = line.getIntersections(shape);

    // Remove the line as we no longer need it.
    line.remove();

    // Every 2 intersections...
    for (let j = 0; j < intersections.length; j++) {
        if (j > 0 && j % 2 === 1) {
            // ...draw a line between intersections points.
            new Path.Line({
                from: [intersections[j - 1].point.x, y],
                to: [intersections[j].point.x, y],
                strokeColor: 'black',
                strokeWidth: shape.bounds.height * 0.5 / LINES_COUNT
            });
        }
    }
}
```